# Integrating Google Docs and Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-docs

Is there any way to integrate Google Docs and Sheets for this case?:

I've a spreadsheet with data: `id`, `Surname`, `NameOfProject`, `Date1`, `Date2`, etc. and a massive number of similar documents to prepare, for example:

```
Letter number : "Id"<br>
Mr/Mrs "Name" had prepeared project called "NameOfProject". It was created on the "Date1" and it was corrected on the "Date2"...
```

---

It would be perfect if we could write it down like:

```
Letter number - (we fill the number) - e.g., 3
```

and it will take expected values from the row with id 3.

Any ideas?

Comment: Use [tag:google-apps-script] or an add-on.

Answer (score 1):

Sort of. Basically, your best bet is to work with what MS Word refers as a mail merge document. The idea is you create a sort of form letter with all necessary input fields entered as placeholders in the body of your letter in a doc. Then you will match up the placeholders in the doc with the columns in your sheet.

I've used the Autocrat script in Google Sheets for a long time with a lot of success and Autocrat is now a free but much more polished addon. There are a lot of nicer addons out there but they're almost all going to cost you to use past the first 100 or 200 merges. Don't get me wrong; they're great. Most people find Autocrat is powerful enough for occasional use to not bother with a subscription-model form letter function.

Autocrat lives in the [Chrome Webstore](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/autocrat/ppgnklghfnlijoafjjkpoakpjjpdkgdj) and on their [website](http://cloudlab.newvisions.org/add-ons/autocrat.).

It's pretty simple to use. You create the form letter in Docs, put placeholders with << and >> on either side of each field name (like << Surname>> but without the space) and then match them up with columns in Google Sheets using the Autocrat wizard. When the wizard completes, Autocrat creates a new Google Doc with the appropriate values filled in for how ever many rows of data you have in your Google Sheet.

It outputs to Google Docs, Sheets, PDF and now Slides. They added the ability to even batch email everything out once completed.